# PhpStorm first line doesn't follow "Align consecutive assignments" setting

Tags: phpstorm

I have a little question while you having a break from coding.

I have set the "Align consecutive assignments" in PhpStorm.

For some reason sometimes the first line of a variable definition block is a little bit unaligned. Screenshot attached.

Basically my question is: Why is the `=` sign of the first line not aligned with all the following lines which are properly aligned after reformat.

[image: Align consecutive assignments]

[image: PhpStorm Setting]

Comment: Please consult our [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: 1) Your 2nd pic (PhpStorm settings) is the same as first one. 2) Does it work OK if it's in a plain PHP file (where you have PHP code only) and not in a mixed file (that may have some quirks from time to time).